# Error: Failed to lookup view "Thank you for joining our wait list!" in views directory "C:\Users\mchio\JoinUs\views"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a student learning Node.js. I need help fixing this look up error in Express. 
Please NOTE, the code is working as expected, meaning, it takes the new user's email address, updates MySQL DB, then increments the UI counter.

The problem is, it is returning both a successful "Thank you for joining our wait list" and "Error: Failed to lookup view..." error messages.

I have spent hours combing stackoverflow and other sites looking for help, but success. This is my first posting here, please help. Thank you!

My code: app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var mysql = require('mysql');


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 


app.get("/", function(req, res){

    var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users";
    connection.query(q, function (err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        var count = results[0].count;
        res.render('home', {counter: count});  
    });
});



app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newuser = {
        email: req.body.email
    };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newuser, function (err, results){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render("Thank you for joining our wait list!");
    });

});
```

App Directory Structure:

C:\Users\mchio\JoinUs

\node_modules (folder), app.js, package.json, package-lock.json (files)

\views (folder)

|--home.ejs (file)
   |

home.ejs file

```
<h1>Welcome to JoinUS.COM</h1>

<p>Please enter your email to join <strong><%=counter%></strong> others on our waitlist. We are a fun START UP focusing on AI. </p>

<form method="POST" action="/register">
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
 <button>Join Now</button>
</form>`enter code here
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! That fixed the problem. I created a new joinus.ejs file under the views folder as recommended by Nguyen Manh Tung, and then updated  res.render('joinus');  I appreciate the help very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
res.render("Thank you for joining our wait list!");
```

So you passed the wrong parameter. It should be the viewName.

So you can pass the joinUs.ejs file inside the view folder. After that you can do something like this

```
res.render('joinUs');
```

In your code, when nodeJs can not find the view, it will raise the error 'Failed to lookup view' as you see. And then it will return the string you passed in the method to user's screen 'Thank you for joining our wait list'. That's why you have 2 results at the same time.